# Can we have HTTPPUT and HTTPPOST in Same Method

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am not sure if this is a silly question.

I have method which does both the task (Update/Add)

I have written method something like this

```
       [HttpPost]
       [HttpPut]
public void MyMethod()
{
}
```

Method is working perfectly fine, I was wondering if this is right way to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to follow the spec, then PUT says that the body IS a representation of the URL you PUT to while POST is more general purpose. Typically, you would POST to a substring of the PUT URI, so in other words PUT some JSON to /posts/my-post whereas you can POST some JSON to /posts/ and possibly get a new URI back.

In this day and age, POST is often used for more general purpose operations but this is the spec.

PUT has specific semantics : "The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the supplied Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to an already existing resource, the enclosed entity SHOULD be considered as a modified version of the one residing on the origin server." per the [spec 9.6](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

POST is: "The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the resource identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line."

Comment: Thank for the answer, i am not writing Rest methods, This are Web apis and hence I am passing everything in Body

Comment: this is from the spec for HTTP, regardless of whether you are building a REST API or something else - if you're asking this, then we can only respond about how HTTP should work